# How to convert (aa)^* U (bb)^* to regex in python?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am doing a textbook problem and I am trying to understand how regex works with Python. In python, I tried doing:

`"(aa)*|(bb)*"`

I seem to be accepting any string and I also want to limit accepting strings that have only {a,b}. I am new to regex, so referring to documentation is a bit confusing at the moment, too. I understand at the moment that as long as our strings are even, then it should be accepted. I appreciate any advice.

Comment: When you want an occurrence of something inside a larger character string you do what you coded.  If it's in there it will find it.  But if you want **only** what is in your regex, you must anchor it to the beginning and ending of the string by starting your regex with "^" (indicating start of "line") and ending with "$' (indicating end of"line").

Comment: Oh I see. I tried like you mentioned ^((aa)*|(bb)*)$ and it seems to be matching strings aa, bb, aaaa, bbbb . . .  and not matching strings like a, b, aabb and so on. would you say there are any cases I should be looking out for that I may not be considering at the moment? The strings I was testing are all looking good and I cannot seem to find a string that may "break" my regex. Is it really that simple looking? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your regex accepts 0 or more (`*`).

Try this:

```
^(?:(?:aa)+|(?:bb)+)$
```

Explanation:

- `^` - Search from start of string
- `(?:(?:aa)+|(?:bb)+)`  - Search for 1 or more occurences of `aa` or `bb`
- `$` - All the way until the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a capture group with an optionally repeated [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to:

- Match strings like `aa` `bb` `aaaa` `bbbb`
- Not match strings like `a` `b` `aabb` or an empty string

**Pattern**

```
^(([ab])\2)\1*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture *group 1*

  - `([ab])\2` Capture *group 2*, match either `a` or `b`  followed by a backreference to group 2
- `)` Close group 1
- `\1*` Optionally repeat a backreference to what is captured in group 1
- `$` End of string

See a [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/RxCdVb/1).